# Network Error when sending file in react native with axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to send a file to a nodejs server from react native using axios, this is my code:

```
const createFormData = (file) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('message', text);
    data.append('receiver',doctorid);
      if(file !== ''){
        data.append('file', {
          type: file.type,
          uri: file.uri,
          name: file.name.replace(/\s/g,'')
        })
      }

      return data;
  }

  const onSend = async() => {
    const newMessages = [...messages]
    newMessages.push({"sender": currentuserID, "id": 339, "message": 'sending...', "attachment": '', "receiver": doctorid, "type": 0},)
    setMessages(newMessages)
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      const data = createFormData(singleFile)


      await appApi.post('/chats', data, {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
      }).then(()=>{

        socket.emit('sendmessage', text, (err) => {
            messageInit()
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))

  }
```

This code works perfectly if there's no image attached, but ones there's an image attached, I get the network error message immediately.

For a little bit of troubleshooting, I tried sending request to my local machine, using ngrok. From ngrok, I realized the request wasn't sent at all to the url. So it just fails immediately, without the request been made to the url.

Anyone with solution to this.

I'm testing on an android emulator

Answer (score 0):

send using formdata
try this

```
let formData = new FormData();
let imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
})
```